# PHP: How to extract a substring from a specified index until the next whitespace or end of line

Tags: php, regex

I have an input string:

`$subject = "This punctuation! And this one. Does n't space that one."`

I also have an array containing exceptions to the replacement I wish to perform, currently with one member:

```
$exceptions = array(
  0 => "n't"
);
```

The reason for the complicated solution I would like to achieve is because this array will be extended in future and could potentially include hundreds of members.

I would like to insert whitespace at word boundaries (duplicate whitespace will be removed later). Certain boundaries should be ignored, though. For example, the exclamation mark and full stops in the above sentence should be surrounded with whitespace, but the apostrophe should not. Once duplicate whitespaces are removed from the final result with `trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $subject));`, it should look like this:

`"This punctuation ! And this one . Does n't space that one ."`

I am working on a solution as follows:

1. Use `preg_match('\b', $subject, $offsets, 'PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE');` to gather an array of indexes where whitespace may be inserted.
2. Iterate over the `$offsets` array.

- split `$subject` from whitespace before the current offset until the next whitespace or end of line.
- check if result of split is contained within `$exceptions` array.
- if result of split is not contained within exceptions array, insert whitespace character at current offset.

So far I have the following code:

```
$subject="This punctuation! And this one. Does n't space that one.";
$pattern = '/\b/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $offsets, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );

if(COUNT($offsets)) {
  $indexes = array();
  for($i=0;$i<COUNT($offsets);$i++) {
    $offsets[$i];
    $substring = '?';

    // Replace $substring with substring from after whitespace prior to $offsets[$i] until next whitespace...

    if(!array_search($substring, $exceptions)) {
      $indexes[] = $offsets[$i];
    }
  }

  // Insert whitespace character at each offset stored in $indexes...

}
```

I can't find an appropriate way to create the `$substring` variable in order to complete the above example.

Comment: why says `Doesn't space that one .`, but is spaced anyway?

Comment: How about: `$res = preg_replace("/(?<!')\b(?!')/", ' ', $subject);`?

Comment: The apostrophe is not spaced. I actually made a mistake and just updated it. Should be `Does n't space that one .` ... so the full stop at the end gets spaced, but not the apostrophe because it belongs to the `n't` match, part of the `$exceptions` array.

Comment: @Toto that only works for specific characters. I need to extend the `$exceptions` array later to potentially include hundreds of members... so then I will just match against that array rather than trying to create a regular expression that satisfies all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$res = preg_replace("/(?:n't|ALL EXCEPTIONS PIPE SEPARATED)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?!^)(?<!\h)\b(?!\h)/", " ", $subject);
echo $res;
```

**Output:**

```
This punctuation ! And this one . Doesn't space that one .
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/GHSE9U/2)

Comment: Always a pleasure ++

Comment: This answer massively exceeded my expectations. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

One "easy" (but not necessarily fast, depending on how many exceptions you have) solution would be to first replace all the exceptions in the string with something unique that doesn't contain any punctuation, then perform your replacements, then convert back the unique replacement strings into their original versions.

Here's an example using `md5` (but could be lots of other things):

```
$subject = "This punctuation! And this one. Doesn't space that one.";

$exceptions = ["n't"];

foreach ($exceptions as $exception) {
    $result = str_replace($exception, md5($exception), $subject);
}

$result = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\s]/i', ' \0', $result);

foreach ($exceptions as $exception) {
    $result = str_replace(md5($exception), $exception, $result);
}

echo $result;  // This punctuation ! And this one . Doesn't space that one .
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/3Fbs6)